# Erro: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///...' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Olá, estou tentando adicionar um arquivo html dentro de outra página atraves de uma diretiva. E da este erro:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///.../AngularJs/Formul%C3%A1rio%20Simples/views/client.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Diretiva:

```
app.directive('myClient', function() { 
return { 
  templateUrl: 'views/client.html' 
}; });
```

Index:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Estudos - AngularJs</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" ></script>
    <!--Controllers-->
    <script src="js/controllers/Client.js" ></script>
    <!--Services-->
    <script src="js/services/emails.js" ></script>
    <!--Directives-->
    <script src="js/directives/client.js" ></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <my-client></my-client>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Execute sua página sem ser pelos dois cliques no arquivo. Senão ele abre com `file:///`. Tente rodar num servidor.

Comment: Pelo visto é por causa disso o problema mesmo, achei que ainda não precisaria de servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa o que pode estar acontecendo é que a sua aplicação esta dando conflito com HTTPS, o que você pode fazer é instalar o módulo npm install http-server e rodar o seguinte comando no seu terminal para abrir o arquivo

```
http-server C:\location\to\app
```

Caso tenha alguma dúvida em relação a isso, tem um outro post relacionado a esse problema e esse é o link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes

Comment: Olá, é exatamente por isso, a falta do servidor. Agora está a funcionar bem, obrigada Alef. :)

Answer (score -2):

Sei que a resposta já esta aceita, porém vai um adendo para quem ja tem o xampp instalado.
Inicie o apache e mova os arquivos para htdocs.

agora basta acessar esse index via localhost/index.html

sendo assim ao tentar fazer essa requisição nao vai mais tentar acessar um file.